# matplotlibwidget Install issue

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I have a strange problem. I am using a program developed in python 2.7 (not by me). The software use matplotlib and I installed it fine. But somehow I still get this error. Anyone has any idea what to check?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Daten\R&D\Labor\pyLogger_RS485\GUI_MasterLogger.py", line 460, in <module>
    mainwindow = MainWindow()
  File "C:\Daten\R&D\Labor\pyLogger_RS485\GUI_MasterLogger.py", line 26, in __init__
    self.initUI()
  File "C:\Daten\R&D\Labor\pyLogger_RS485\GUI_MasterLogger.py", line 56, in initUI
    self.ui = uic.loadUi('uiGUI_TCCO2_MasterLogger.ui')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\__init__.py", line 238, in loadUi
    return DynamicUILoader(package).loadUi(uifile, baseinstance, resource_suffix)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\Loader\loader.py", line 71, in loadUi
    return self.parse(filename, resource_suffix, basedir)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 951, in parse
    actor(elem)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 790, in createUserInterface
    self.traverseWidgetTree(elem)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 768, in traverseWidgetTree
    handler(self, child)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 242, in createWidget
    self.traverseWidgetTree(elem)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 768, in traverseWidgetTree
    handler(self, child)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 242, in createWidget
    self.traverseWidgetTree(elem)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 768, in traverseWidgetTree
    handler(self, child)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 242, in createWidget
    self.traverseWidgetTree(elem)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 768, in traverseWidgetTree
    handler(self, child)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 233, in createWidget
    self.stack.push(self.setupObject(widget_class, parent, elem))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\uiparser.py", line 194, in setupObject
    obj =  self.factory.createQObject(clsname, name, args, is_attribute)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\objcreator.py", line 106, in createQObject
    factory = self.findQObjectType(classname)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\objcreator.py", line 131, in findQObjectType
    w = module.search(classname)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\Loader\qobjectcreator.py", line 107, in search
    module = __import__(mname, {}, {}, (cls,))
ImportError: No module named matplotlibwidget
```

Thanks in advance,
Umberto

Comment: I _think_ `matplotlibwidget` is actually part of `pythonxy`.

Comment: Thanks. Will try and let you know! But does that mean I need to reinstall python? I already installed several modules :(

Comment: Facing mysteriously the same problem with python3.6 matplotlib3.1 and pyqt5. Have you fixed it?